# How would one say "gracious" with grac- instead of graci-?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

If one is gracious by showing social grace, they're *gracia*. But if one dispenses or exhibits grace, compassion and forgiveness regardless of the recipient's merit, would they be *graca*, *gracema*, *grachava*, *gracplena* or *gracdona*? Dictionaries seem to list *graco* by itself without defining any derivations and I haven't seen any good examples of *gracious* that aren't about the social virtue. Tekstaro has *gracplene* but seemingly nothing related to the others. I would like to know which expression would be more natural grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

*Graco* (= *Difavoro*, divine grace, something close to ‘mercy’) is a religious term in Christianity, maybe in other religions, too.

*Gracia* is more like graceful, charming, pleasing. The first definition of *gracia* in the *Plena Ilustrita Vortaro* is *Plaĉa pro ia diskreta, senpena k senpeza harmonio en la movoj, gestoj aŭ sinteno*. The second meaning relates to pleasing thinness, being slim.

If I understand correctly you are looking for words like *favorkora*, *kompleza*, *indulgema*, *kompatema*.

Comment: I'm wondering more if I would be able to describe someone using an adjective derived from graco as opposed to other mercy terms.

Comment: The adjective is _graca_ but the word only relates to grace (kindness) of God. _Graco_ translates _grace_ only in this narrow religious sense. For _mercy_ use _kompat(em)o_ or one of the other words I suggested.

Comment: I apologise, the use would be in that religious sense. In that case would "Dio estas graca" appropriate?

Comment: _Dio estas gracoplena_ would be appropriate here.